# Highcharts Drilldown with breadcrumb navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts

Is there any way to get highchart drilldown with breadcrum navigation.
for example in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-drilldown/) where browsers data is present. I want to display breadcrum as `browsers / chrome`

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts doesn't offer this feature in the regular API. You can report this idea on Highcharts UserVoice channel: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Or create it by yourself by using **SVGRenderer** feature.
Basic demo from which you can start: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7eomv6kw/

```
chart.browsersLabel = chart.renderer.label('browsers', 0, 0)
  .css({
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  })
  .attr({
    fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    padding: 8,
    r: 5,
    zIndex: 6
  })
  .add();
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label